# htaccess match & sign

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want have a rule in .htaccess to forward /test/ABC&D to /test.php?s=ABC&D

I tried the following rule. The result forward to /test.php?s=ABC . '&D' is missing from url.

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^.]+)$ /test.php?s=$1 [PT]
```

Comment: Do you have control over the original source of that URL `/test/ABC&D`? It should be changed at its source, as it is not a valid URL unless the `&` is encoded. `ABC%26D`

Comment: Yes, i tried to change URL to `ABC%26D`. I try to output the parameter in test.php with `echo $_GET['s'];` The output is still `ABC` without `&D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that behaviour because it considers `&` is a separator in query string.
As a result, you have first data `s` containing `ABC` and second data `D` empty.

To pass `&` in url, you have to encode it: `%26`.
That's why `B` flag exists. You can try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^.]+)$ /test.php?s=$1 [PT,B]
```

More info on `B` flag [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b)